# Sysinternals pslist: client does not have required rights

Tags: windows, process, remote-access

I'm on an "ancient" machine running Windows 2000 right now.

I'm trying to get the list of running processes on remote computer running Windows 7 x64 using Sysinternals `pslist`:

```
pslist \\192.168.199.2 -u admin -p password
```

where `admin` and `password` correspond to an account with Administrative privileges on that computer. But it fails saying that the client does not have required rights.

At the same time, I can open hidded administrative shares on that computer by intering, for example,

```
\\192.168.199.2\c$
```

in Windows Explorer and have full access to the file system as `admin`.

I also can successfully execute the following obtaining the complete directory listing:

```
net use \\192.168.199.2\Admin$ /user:admin
dir \\192.168.199.2\Admin$
net use \\192.168.199.2\Admin$ /delete
```

On [this page](http://forum.sysinternals.com/please-read-before-posting_topic15919.html) it is said that if these commands work, then it it should be possible to run a PSTools command to `\\192.168.199.2` as well.

Of course if I run `pslist` on that machine directly being logged under the `admin` account, it works perfectly.

Why `pslist` fails to get the list of running processes remotely? What can I do as an Administrator to allow remote processes manipulation using Sysinternals psTools?

Comment: Take a look, Alexey: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/96decbd7-16eb-44a7-aa64-5ab1eeff976a/could-not-start-psexec-service-on-target-machine-access-is-denied?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: @duDE Thank you very much, using hints from that thread I was able to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in the following way:

1) It was necessary to run the `Remote Registry` Service on the target machine running Windows 7. [This article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754820.aspx) describes the steps:

> 1. Click **Start**, click in the **Start Search** box, type `services.msc`,
>      and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Microsoft Management Console will start with the
>      Services snap-in open.
> 2. In the console pane, right-click `Remote Registry` and click **Start**.

Using this Console I have configured the `Remote Registry` Service to start automatically.

2) On the client machine I run another copy of `cmd.exe` using account name and password of the target machine (note the backslash separating the IP and the user name!):

```
runas /netonly /user:192.168.199.2\admin cmd
```

After executing the above command the password will be prompted. After typing the password and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> new window with the title `"cmd ( run as 192.168.199.2\admin )"` opens.

3) In the new window I execute:

```
pslist \\192.168.199.2
```

This works as expected. Note that it is not needed to specify the user name and password.

I can also kill any process on the remote machine, for example killing remote `cmd.exe` process:

```
pskill \\192.168.199.2 cmd
```

... or run the `cmd.exe` on the remote machine and interact with it in the convenient way (as if I would be loggen into the remote machine directly):

```
psexec \\192.168.199.2 cmd
```

After executing the last command the window title changes to `\\192.168.199.2: cmd`. In this window I can run psTools available on the remote machine, no need to specify the target host anymore. Very handy!

Executing `exit` allows to exit the remote `cmd.exe` process and changes the window title back to `"cmd ( run as 192.168.199.2\admin )"`.

Addition of `start` at the beginning starts the remote `cmd.exe` process in separate window:

```
start psexec \\192.168.199.2 cmd
```

Comment: Nice solution, +1 !